# Nicky is thinking of giving up her job

Tags: verbs, present-tense, present-continuous

> Nicky is thinking of giving up her job

In this sentence why have give+ing? I know *give up* means *release*.

I want to know why in this sentence uses "giving up"?

Comment: yes, but I didn't understand that sentence.

Comment: Why not? It seems straightforward.

Comment: As @Xanne says, it's pretty clear: prepositions take objects, and gerunds can function as objects . . . and there you go.

Comment: _One_ meaning of 'give up' is 'release'. In this case, it means 'leave, stop doing'.

Comment: It's a fact of English grammar that while prepositions don't generally accept _to-_ infinitivals as complements, many can take gerund-participials (_ing_ clauses). This is due to the fact that gerund-participials (_ing_ forms) are more like NPs than infinitivals are.

Comment: One quirk is that "Nicky thinks about giving up her job" is more common/idiomatic than "Nicky thinks of giving up her job". Note that "Nicky is thinking about giving up her job" would also be fine. But following the present continuous, "of" feels natural, whereas it feels less natural with the simple present.

Comment: What do you think it should be?

Comment: This use of _think_ (with _of_ and a gerund) means she is considering doing it, and the use of the progressive means she's continuing, i.e, it's serious consideration. It does not mean _she thinks about it_ (which means she occasionally day-dreams about it), not does it mean _she thinks of it_, which merely means it's one option she has.

Answer (score -1):

One should not think of "giving" as give+ing. "Giving" is a whole separate word. It can be either a gerund (noun derived from a verb) or a present participle (verb form). Here it is a present participle.

"*Giving up*" means (in one sense) the act of releasing or abandoning. It is also a very commonly used phrase in English.

Answer (score -2):

You are correct.  *Give up* means to release.  *Give up* also follows the rules of English grammar.

*Giving* is the present participle of *give*.  It conveys the sense of a continual or on going action.

> Niki is thinking about *swimming* across the river.

> Niki is thinking about *giving* up her job.

Both swimming and giving are present participles.

Perhaps the confusion is from the double present participles, *thinking* and *giving*?  This a perfectly acceptable usage of the participles.  Both actions are ongoing.  Niki's personal *thinking* is ongoing and what she is actually thinking about, *swimming*, is also ongoing in her thoughts.

Anytime you use a present participle as the principle verb in your sentence, you must use a present participle to refer *directly* to any subsequent verbs/actions done by the subject.

> William is *arguing* about *paying* the bill.

> Tom is *reconsidering* *purchasing* the turkeys.

> Scott is *anticipating* *travelling* to Inverness.

Comment: Feedback on downvote would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What does "Give up also follows the rules of English grammar." mean exactly? You keep repeating that "giving" is the present participle of "give" and completely ignoring that the sentence is about "giving up". Why have you changed the name from Nicky to Niki? Why have you changed "giving up" to "swimming"? This seems like you are piecing together bits from some source instead of writing an answer about something you know. It's very confusing. Just FYI, the [Code of Conduct prohibits posting AI generated content without appropriate attribution.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/393682/273494).

Comment: You asked for feedback and I obliged. That's not aggressive. I have no personal bias against you; I don't know you and I'm sorry my directness upsets you. All I know is what you've written and it's confusing. You mention "my sources" - any sources you're paraphrasing from need to be [properly referenced](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/referencing). Also, you have a typo... "Anytime you use..." (which is unrelated to my downvote).

Comment: I think you saw an answer from someone with a reputation of 10 and decided to let them know their place.  Thanks again for pointing out how the name Niki was changed from the original post.  I think that will be valuable for me to keep in mind going forward.

Comment: I only look at posts, not who wrote them. I would give you the same feedback if you had 100K reputation. It is important to address the question as written by the author. Making a lot of small changes, like the spelling of names, is a technique used by some people to obfuscate the fact that they are copying from another source. If you aren't doing that, that's great! But no-one here knows you well enough to know you wouldn't do that, so it would be better to use the exact same examples that the author is asking about, and then expand your explanation with other examples.

Comment: -1 "Giving" is a *gerund* here, the complement of the preposition "about", and not a present participle at all (unless you consider gerund and present participle to be a single grammatical form, which I do not). Also, the word "swimming" here doesn't represent a "*sense of a continual or ongoing action*", since the action hasn't started yet. Further, swimming is not "*ongoing in her thoughts*". Rather, the structure *[ "think about" + verb+"ing" ]* roughly means "decide whether to verb". The verb can even be an instant action: "*She's thinking about turning the light off*", so not continuous.